# How to sort users that have more unread messages to appear first in mysql results

Tags: mysql

Am trying to sort users who have more unread messages to appear first in mysql results while including also the ones with read messages
appearing as last

Am using mysql 5.6.17
table structure

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| msgID     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userID    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msgText   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| msgStatus | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| userName  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

my data is like this with out sorting

```
+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
| msgID | userID | msgText           | msgStatus | userName |
+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
|     1 |      1 | hi                | unread    | Francis  |
|     2 |      2 | hello             | unread    | Emma     |
|     3 |      1 | good              | unread    | Francis  |
|     4 |      1 | your not easy     | read      | Francis  |
|     5 |      2 | just no that      | unread    | Emma     |
|     6 |      2 | don't lose it bro | unread    | Emma     |
|     7 |      2 | good keep it up   | unread    | Emma     |
|     8 |      3 | i don't hate it   | unread    | John     |
+-------+--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+
```

if i run the group query `"select userID, userName FROM msg GROUP BY userID";`
 it groups the results like this

```
+--------+----------+
| userID | userName |
+--------+----------+
|      1 | Francis  |
|      2 | Emma     |
|      3 | John     |
+--------+----------+
```

but i need the ones with more of their "msgStatus" equaling to "unread" to appear on top in order including even those who have "read" on "msgStatus" only, thanks guys in advance

```
select userID, userName FROM msg GROUP BY userID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to try to compute for each userId and userName an **unread count** and a **read count**. Given those 4 computed columns, you simply select distinct **userId**s giving preference to those rows where **unread count** is > **unread count**. The computation would be simplified if MySql supported full outer joins, which it doesn't. This has to be emulated by the union of right and left outer joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userId, userName FROM (
        SELECT sq1.userId,
        sq1.userName,
        sq1.unreadCount,
        IFNULL(sq2.readCount,0) AS readCount FROM
            (SELECT userId, userName, count(*) AS unreadCount FROM msg
            WHERE msgStatus = 'unread'
            GROUP BY userId, userName) sq1
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT userId, userName, count(*) AS readCount FROM msg
            WHERE msgStatus = 'read'
            GROUP BY userId, userName) sq2
        ON sq1.userId = sq2.userId
    UNION
        SELECT sq2.userId,
        sq2.userName,
        IFNULL(sq1.unreadCount,0) AS unreadCount,
        sq2.readCount FROM
            (SELECT userId, userName, count(*) AS unreadCount FROM msg
            WHERE msgStatus = 'unread'
            GROUP BY userId, userName) sq1
        RIGHT JOIN
            (SELECT userId, userName, count(*) AS readCount FROM msg
            WHERE msgStatus = 'read'
            GROUP BY userId, userName) sq2
        ON sq1.userId = sq2.userId
) sq
ORDER BY IF(unreadCount > readCount, unreadCount, 0) DESC, userId
;
```

Comment: Much less straightforward than forpas' answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sort by `sum(msgStatus = 'unread')` descending:

```
select userID, userName 
FROM msg 
GROUP BY userID
order by sum(msgStatus = 'unread') desc
```